# Cannot add Microsoft.Azure.Devices to ASP.NET 5 project: can't find fx/System.Net.Http.Formatting

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, dnx, azure-iot-hub

When adding the Microsoft.Azure.Devices NuGet package (I've tried 1.0.0, 1.0.2, and 1.0.4) to an ASP.NET 5 (Web API 2) project, the reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting is marked as not resolvable with

NU1001 The dependency fx/System.Net.Http.Formatting could not be resolved

There are several NU1001 issues out there, but none whose causes seem to map to this one. The best reference is [this one on Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/158), but the resolution details were sketchy.

The reference DLL is indeed marked as Copy Local when the package is brought into a 'legacy' assembly package, so I can see why it might not find it, but can't determine the right way to fix it.

In my actual use-case, Microsoft.Azure.Devices is being referenced by a .NET assembly package and THAT is then included as a project reference in the ASP.NET 5 project, and indeed that gives the same error as trying to directly reference the NuGet from the ASP.NET 5 project.

We're using dnx452 as the only framework referenced in the project.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this with version 1.0.5 and it installed successfully for me.

Comment: I've been meaning to get around to this... yes, they fixed the NuGet packaging so that the non-framework DLL System.Net.Http.Formatting is no longer referenced in the FrameworkAssemblies section.   See https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1132#issuecomment-207218861 for details... and a special shout out to @dmpontifex for his help!